# Upgrading from 4GB to 16 GB RAM HP 250 G2

Tags: memory

I have a Hp Laptop (Pentium, By default comes with a 4GB RAM) 
The System Model is HP 250 G2 NoteBook PC

Can this pc be upgradable to 16GB RAM?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the spec sheet for that HP model it looks like you can. (https://support.hp.com/si-en/document/c04044564#AbT2)

**Upgradeable to 16384MB with optional 8192MB SODIMMs in slots 1 and 2**

RAM type this board takes is **DDR3L SDRAM (1600 MHz)**

[Another way of finding this information out is using Crucial's (Memory supplier)](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/systemscanner?cm_re=us-top-nav-_-us-flyout-memory-_-us-memory-ad-scanner) scanning tool;